# Having some trouble deploying react app and express/node.js backend on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, deployment

I want to serve my react front-end on localhost:5000, and the api requests will go to localhost:5000/api/some-path.

I have seen some similar questions and from what I have understood :

- Add proxy in package.json
- Serve static files from build folder

relevant part of package.json:

```
  "proxy" : "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Relevant part of server.js :

```
const PORT = 5000 || process.env.port;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
});
```

Commands for production :

```
$ npm run build
$ serve -s build
```

The issue is that, each fetch request's response is the index.html file.

Note that, in the dev build everything was working fine. I was starting react app from port 3000 and requests were going to localhost:5000/api/path responding with json data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this line : `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));`
The build folder was outside the folder which contains the file server.js.
Corrected to : `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));`

Answer (score 0):

As someone new to code, I've recently had a hard time deploying react and node. How I ended up doing it was:

1. Build the react app with npm run build
2. Copy the build folder in the root of the node.js project
3. Include this code in the index or app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = 5000 || process.env.port;
app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

4. Start the app with node index.js or node app.js and that's it